# Flask throwing SQL query as a syntax error

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pymysql

I am trying to run a query through Flask using a curser. I checked my query on a syntax checker and it said there were no errors in my code; however, when I run my file with python3 it gives me a syntax error.
Here is my code:

```py
CREATE 
OR REPLACE VIEW flight_expanded AS WITH flight_city AS 
(
   SELECT
      flight_number,
      airline,
      airplane_id,
      departure_date,
      departure_time,
      arrival_date,
      arrival_time,
      departure_airport,
      departure_city,
      arrival_airport,
      arrival_city,
      status,
      base_price 
   FROM
      flight 
      JOIN
         (
            SELECT
               name AS departure_airport_name,
               city AS departure_city 
            FROM
               airport
         )
         as s 
      JOIN
         (
            SELECT
               name AS arrival_airport_name,
               city AS arrival_city 
            FROM
               airport
         )
         as t 
   WHERE
      departure_airport = s.departure_airport_name 
      AND arrival_airport = t.arrival_airport_name
)
,
flight_size AS 
(
   SELECT
      flight_number as flight_num,
      airline AS airl,
      IFNULL(COUNT(ticket.ID), 0) as number_of_passengers 
   FROM
      flight NATURAL 
      LEFT JOIN
         ticket 
   GROUP BY
      flight_number,
      airline
)
SELECT
   flight_number,
   airline,
   airplane_id,
   departure_date,
   departure_time,
   arrival_date,
   arrival_time,
   departure_airport,
   departure_city,
   arrival_airport,
   arrival_city,
   status,
   base_price,
   IF(number_of_passengers < 0.7*number_of_seats, base_price, 1.2*base_price) AS sale_price,
   number_of_seats,
   number_of_passengers 
FROM
   (
      SELECT
         * 
      FROM
         flight_city AS s 
         JOIN
            (
               SELECT
                  ID,
                  airline AS al,
                  number_of_seats 
               FROM
                  airplane
            )
            AS t 
            ON (s.airplane_ID = t.ID 
            AND s.airline = t.al)
   )
   AS u 
   JOIN
      flight_size 
      ON (flight_size.flight_num = u.flight_number 
      AND flight_size.airl = u.airline)
```

Here is the error I get in the terminal when i run `python3 airline.py`:

```
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
syntax to use near 'flight_city AS (SELECT 
flight_number,airline,airplane_id,departure_date,departur' at line 1")
```

I would also like to mention this query works on my teammates windows system; however, does not work on my mac using MAMP. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I don't have mysql installed on my system, it's just running through MAMP

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it's working on your teammate's machine but not yours is because of version compatibility. This is not a Python issue per se, because it's telling you that the issue is in the SQL syntax.  I would suggest that you update MySQL and try running the code again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but both of us only have MySQL through MAMP and not installed system wide.